# Django: How is a RelatedManager object instantiated?

Tags: python, django, model

Suppose I have two `models`: `Book` and `Author`.

If I now added a `ForeignKey field` to `Book` connecting it to `Author`, and instantiated a `Book object` - then I also have access to that `Book object` through the `Author object` it is connected to (via .`book_set`, if no `related_name` specified). From what I have understood reading the documentation, this access is provided through a `Related Manager object` on the `Author object`.

When is that `RelatedManager-object` created? Or is it already an `object` on each `Author object`, but gets connected to each Book object upon instantiation of a new `Book`? If so, how does it get connected to the `Book object?`

**This is not mentioned in the documentation to my knowledge.**

In the documentation:

> If a model has a ForeignKey, instances of the foreign-key model will
>   have access to a Manager that returns all instances of the first
>   model.

Comment: What do you need that information for and have tried looking into the code?

Comment: My error is **'RelatedManager' object is not iterable**. I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481893/relatedmanager-object-is-not-subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Django, it will give you some tracks:

```
>>> Author.book_set
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ReverseManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x7f41aa1920f0>
>>> Author.objects.first().book_set
<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager object at 0x7f41a9e46828>
```