# 'RelatedManager' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

thanks for your time.
i'm trying to get the first images of a foreignKey image model and display with the other fields

i've read some questions and docs about related models and the best i got was to create a function on my models to call it after just to get the first image.

models.py:

```
class Veiculos (models.Model):
    YEAR_CHOICES = []
    for r in range(1960, (datetime.now().year+1)):
        YEAR_CHOICES.append((r, r))

    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    potencia = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    cor = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    preco = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    ano = models.IntegerField(('ano'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.now().year)
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Categorias')
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.modelo, self.preco)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category2')

    def first_image(self):
        return self.images.first()  

def get_image_filename(instance, filename):
    modelo = instance.veicle.modelo
    slug = slugify(modelo)
    return "veiculos_imagens/%s-%s" % (slug, filename)


class Imagens (models.Model):
    veicle = models.ForeignKey(Veiculos, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename)
```

views.py:

```
def amp_category(request):
    queryset = Veiculos.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'amp/category.amp.html', {'veiculos': queryset})
```

category.amp.html:

```
{% extends "amp/base.amp.html" %} {% block tittle %}
<title>ok</title>{% endblock tittle %} {% block content %}

<body>
    <h1>ok2</h1>
    {% for veiculo in veiculos %}
    <h2>{{veiculo.modelo}}</h2>
    <amp-img src="{{ veiculo.first_image.url }}" alt="ok" width="300" height="340"></amp-img>
    {% endfor %}

</body>

{% endblock %}

</html>
```

i'm getting the queryset objects although none imaged displayed
https://github.com/lucasrf27/dealership

Comment: Note, image fields don't have a `src` attribute, it is `url`. Also, your method is a bit pointless; you could do the whole thing in the template: `{{ veiculo.images.all.0.url }}`

Comment: i've tried it and displays me nothing. im getting the queryset as veiculo although the images don't displays nothing. by url it means the one created by get_image_filename() right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be:

```
def first_image(self):
    return self.images.first()
```

or you can subscript with:

```
def first_image(self):
    return self.images.all()[0]
```

You can not subscript the `self.images` relation itself, you need to use a `.all()` or `.first()`.

Note that there is a small difference between the two. If there are no related images, then `self.images.first()` will return `None`, whereas `self.images.all()[0]` will raise an error.

Comment: i've tried both ways and don't' get the error anymore although get the page without the images. i've tried to create an object calling the function on a ListVIew and a FBV on my views and still gets  the page but without images. should i set this first_image in views besides models?

Comment: @locasrf27: your template contains an error: you need to use `.first_image.url`, not `first_image.src`

Comment: yeah i changed it either it becomes 
for veiculo in veiculos
{{veiculo.first_image.url}}
im gonna update the post

Comment: just a seccond setting the whole project on github

Comment: @lucasrf27: sorry, should be `{{ veiculo.first_image.imagem.url }}` (so with `imagem`).

Comment: Thank you so much sir, i think its the second or third questio that you helps me with.
but why the .imagem? am i calling the objects of imagem doing it?

Comment: @locasrf27: because the `.first_image` is an `Imagens` object, you need to use its `imagem` field (the `ImageField` to get access to the image its url).

Comment: hello, sir willen i'm having a trouble on setting gallery with amp-lightbox would you take a look please? thank you so much sir anyway